# MySQL: How to add a column if it doesn't already exist?

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I want to add a column to a table, but I don't want it to fail if it has already been added to the table. How can I achieve this?

```
# Add column fails if it already exists 
ALTER TABLE `TableName` ADD `ColumnName` int(1) NOT NULL default '0';
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [add column to mysql table if it does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972922/add-column-to-mysql-table-if-it-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 18):

Use the following in a stored procedure:

```
IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT NULL
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
           WHERE table_name = 'tablename'
             AND table_schema = 'db_name'
             AND column_name = 'columnname')  THEN

  ALTER TABLE `TableName` ADD `ColumnName` int(1) NOT NULL default '0';

END IF;
```

Reference:

- [The INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS  Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html)

Comment: Why the `!=` comparison. I suspect there must be a good reason for it.

Comment: @SaadFarooq: Corrected the column check, but the syntax is otherwise correct -- [COLUMN is optional if you check the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: I get a syntax error. Seems to choke after `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`. Did the schema change in MySQL 5.6?