# mysql IF EXISTS returning error

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL: How to add a column if it doesn't already exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242080/mysql-how-to-add-a-column-if-it-doesnt-already-exist)

A tool I use is running this query but it's failing. I'm trying to help debug but cannot figure out what's wrong:

```
IF EXISTS( SELECT NULL FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE table_name = 'TOWNY_RESIDENTS' 
AND table_schema = 'minecraft'
AND column_name != 'town-ranks') 
THEN
ALTER TABLE TOWNY_RESIDENTS (ADD 
`town-ranks`  mediumtext,
`nation-ranks`  mediumtext
);
```

The inner select query works fine. It seems the if exists syntax is wrong but I can't figure out how. Examples on website like SO show similar ideas...

The error is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS( SELECT NULL FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'TOW' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`ALTER TABLE` does not support `IF EXISTS` in MySQL. You can run your `ALTER TABLE` statement and ignore the resulting errors.

Another option is to do a `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` on information_schema to generate the `ALTER TABLE` statement if necessary, and then source that file to execute the `ALTER TABLE` statement.

Comment: Is there any query-only solution to check? We could just run alter without checking, or SHOW COLUMNS and parsing the output for the field, but I'm just covering my bases.

Comment: Because even this doesn't work: IF NOT EXISTS( (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'TOWNY_RESIDENTS') ) THEN SELECT 1 FROM TOWNY_RESIDENTS;

Comment: There are dozens of mysql threads indicating that alter table works fine with the if exists...