# How to add if statements in MySQL alter command?

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `application` (
`appid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`appcode` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`parentid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`appname` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`appcat` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`appsubcat` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`appdesc` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`active` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y'   
);
TRUNCATE TABLE  ivumetastore.application;
```

adding alter command:

```
ALTER TABLE application MODIFY COLUMN `appid` int(11) NOT NULL
AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

As I am running these 2 commands in separate bat files, getting error for 2nd time ,because already appid PK is present. How can I make it IF NOT EXISTS for Alter command, or truncate all indices, so that it will create again?

Comment: You can create a stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571611/mysql-alter-table-if-column-not-exists) we can try doing the following from a stored procedure:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
    WHERE
        TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_db_name' AND
        TABLE_NAME = 'application'    AND
        CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'PRIMARY') THEN

    ALTER TABLE application
    MODIFY COLUMN `appid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;

END IF;
```