# ADD column if not exists in mysql

Tags: mysql

I keep getting an error when I run this on mysql5.7
What am I doing wrong. I basically just want to add a column if the column doesnt already exist

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ALIASCOLUMN;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE ALIASCOLUMN()
BEGIN
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION BEGIN END;
ALTER TABLE 'human_api_procedure' ADD COLUMN 'alias' varchar(255);
END //
DELIMITER;
CALL ALIASCOLUMN();
DROP PROCEDURE ALIASCOLUMN;
```

Comment: What is the error this is returning to you?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in a stored procedure:

```
IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT *
             FROM 'tablename'
             WHERE table_name = 'tablename'
             AND table_schema = 'db_name'
             AND column_name = 'columnname')  THEN

  ALTER TABLE `human_api_procedure` ADD `alias` varchar(255) ;

END IF;
```

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571611/mysql-alter-table-if-column-not-exists/29428841#29428841). It may help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>DDL statements within a procedure have to be executed as dynamic SQL. (I think that's true, I'd need to check the docs to verify.)</strike>

Also, identifiers (table names, column names) should not be enclosed in single quotes. Single quotes are delimiters for string literals.

I'd expect this statement to fail with a syntax error:

```
ALTER TABLE 'human_api_procedure' ADD COLUMN 'alias' varchar(255)
```

This

```
ALTER TABLE  human_api_procedure  ADD COLUMN  alias  varchar(255)
            ^                   ^            ^     ^
```

or this

```
ALTER TABLE `human_api_procedure` ADD COLUMN `alias` varchar(255)
            ^                   ^            ^     ^
```

would be valid syntax. We could also use double quotes around identifiers, if ANSI_QUOTES is included in sql_mode.

---

To execute an `ALTER TABLE` statement in the context of a MySQL stored program, we could do something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE aliascolumn()
BEGIN

  SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE human_api_procedure ADD COLUMN alias varchar(255)';
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

---

> MySQL permits routines to contain DDL statements, such as CREATE and DROP.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html

The pattern demonstrated above, using the PREPARE/EXECUTE/DEALLOCATE would allow execution of for dynamic SQL, not just static SQL text.