# Send a Procedure in a query from Node to MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, stored-procedures, delimiter

I'm building a backend for my food application, and I need to create columns in food table and INSERT rows in nutrients table. I'm constructing a query, there are ~60 nutrients in every food, and there are hundreds of different nutrient types.

I used one of answers from [MySQL: ALTER TABLE if column not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571611/mysql-alter-table-if-column-not-exists/31989541#31989541) as my template

```
            for (let i = 0; i < food.nutrients.length; i++) {
              createColumnsString += `
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS \`create_column\`; 
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE \`create_column\`()
BEGIN
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION BEGIN END;
ALTER TABLE \`food\` ADD COLUMN \`${food.nutrients[i].nutrientNumber}\` VARCHAR(45); 
INSERT INTO \`nutrients\` (nutrientid, nutrientname, unit) VALUES ("${food.nutrients[i].nutrientNumber}", "${food.nutrients[i].nutrientName}", "${food.nutrients[i].unitName}"); 
END // 
DELIMITER ; 
CALL \`create_column\`(); 
DROP PROCEDURE \`create_column\`; `;
            }
            console.log(createColumnsString);
            db.query(createColumnsString);
```

the console.log(createColumnsString) for each nutrient prints this in Node console:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `create_column`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `create_column`()
BEGIN
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION BEGIN END;
ALTER TABLE `food` ADD COLUMN `269.3` VARCHAR(45);
INSERT INTO `nutrients` (nutrientid, nutrientname, unit) VALUES ("269.3", "Sugars, Total NLEA", "G");
END //
DELIMITER ;
CALL `create_column`();
DROP PROCEDURE `create_column`;
```

And it works when i paste it to MySQL Workbench. I can put all ~60 queries one after another and it does what it's supposed to do.

On the other hand, db.query(createColumnsString) gives me this:

```
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //\n" +
    'CREATE PROCEDURE `create_column`()\n' +
    'BEGIN\n' +
    "DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER F' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 1,
  sql: '\n' +
    'DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `create_column`; \n' +
    'DELIMITER //\n' +
    'CREATE PROCEDURE `create_column`()\n' +
    'BEGIN\n' +
    'DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION BEGIN END;\n' +
    'ALTER TABLE `food` ADD COLUMN `303` VARCHAR(45); \n' +
    'INSERT INTO `nutrients` (nutrientid, nutrientname, unit) VALUES ("303", "Iron, Fe", "MG"); \n' +
    'END // \n' +
    'DELIMITER ; \n' +
    'CALL `create_column`(); \n' +
    'DROP PROCEDURE `create_column`; \n' +
    'DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `create_column`; \n' +
```

I'm using mysql library for connection. Does it even permit the use of DELIMITER? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thats a **terrible** terrible idea. Create a seperate table for this information and have a id column to link it to the `food` table. Search for [Relational Database Design for Beginners](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=relational+database+design+for+beginners&ia=web)

Comment: isn't it exactly what I'm trying to do? I have separate tables for nutrients and food, one link between them being the id. In id column (food table) there is just 1 value

Comment: You are in a loop of `food.nutrients.length` and for each iteration you are attempting to add a column to the `food` table? Or am I getting that wrong

Comment: PS I dont see why you are trying to create a proceedure to do this in either?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: So the `food` table will end up with many many column, one for each nutrient. Thats what is wrong

Comment: I would like to answer your question, but procedure is the only 1 that works at the moment

Comment: How should I connect nutrients to food then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Food table to contain the food info.

```
id int
name varchar(30)
... etc etc
```

Create a Nutriets table to hold nutrient info.

```
id int
nutrientname    varchar(30)
unit            _not sure of type_
. . . etc etc
```

Then as many foods will have the same nutrients in them you need a xref table, or link table to connect them

That table is simply something like this

food_nutrients table

```
id          int
food_id     int
nutrient_id int
```

Nowyou can link any food to any nutrient, all you need is either the `id` of the `food` or the `id` of the `nutrient` to be able to list all a foods nutrients, or all the food that contain any nutrient.

Comment: So you are telling me it's better to have a table with (foods * nutrients) rows and 3 columns than a table with foods rows and nutrients columns? I'm new to SQL so it seems kinda weird to me

Comment: Yes, randomly adding columns to accomodate new data is a bad idea

Comment: I went for a walk and I think i understood it :D It's gonna be better since not every cell in the food row will have data. And I can probably do it without procedures. Will update tommorow.