# SQLite - add a column if it does not exist

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqflite

I am new to SQLite. I want to add a column if it does not exist.

How to check if the column name exists and then add if it does not?

I tried

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN colname INTEGER ON CONFLICT IGNORE
```

But it shows an error

> Result: near "ON": syntax error

Any advice how it can be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571611/mysql-alter-table-if-column-not-exists

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First get a list of table column names - as list - with something like:

```
select group_concat(c.name) from pragma_table_info('table_name') c;
```

Then do a CASE expression on whether the new column name you want to add exists in the list above. More info at: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

Comment: I used "PRAGMA table_info($_tableName);" which gave all column names and extracted the column which i needed from the map to know if it exists.