# How to use select inside if for MySQL

Tags: mysql, subquery

I got an "select is not valid at the position, expecting an expression" error for my query:

```
insert into tbl_disease(nid, name, diagnosed_time, treatment_times, inherited) 
values ('314759','high blood pressure','2015-07-01','4',
( if (select count(distinct disease_name) from tbl_disease where disease_name='high blood pressure') >0, 'Y', 'N'));
```

post I've read: [MYSQL SELECT WITHIN IF Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774837/mysql-select-within-if-statement)

Can you point out how can I correct this? Any help is appreciated! Many thanks!!!

Comment: Use INSERT .. SELECT instead. Or CASE WHEN EXISTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
insert into tbl_disease(nid, name, diagnosed_time, treatment_times, inherited) 
values ('314759',
        'high blood pressure',
        '2015-07-01',
        '4',
        CASE WHEN EXISTS ( select NULL 
                           from tbl_disease 
                           where disease_name='high blood pressure' ) 
             THEN 'Y' 
             ELSE 'N'
             END);
```

Comment: Hi @akina, from this answer, it seems 'N' can never be generated, it's either Null or 'Y'. is it right?

Comment: @daisy No. NULL is not returned. EXISTS tests for a row presence (with any value, NULL included) and returns either TRUE (treated as 1) or FALSE (treated as 0). You may use any other literal (for example, `select 1` or `select 'present'` - it doesn't matter).

Answer (score 1):

`IF` syntax is `IF(boolean expression, result expression if true, result expression if false)`.  You can use a comparison against a subquery returning a single value as the boolean expression, but the subquery needs to also be delimited by parentheses.

So you need to say:

```
if((select ...) > 0,'Y','N')
```

With only one `(` after the if, it is expecting an expression next.  `(select ...)` or `(select ...) > 0` is an expression; `select ...` is not.

Adding all the missing parentheses, you should end up with:

```
insert into tbl_disease(nid, name, diagnosed_time, treatment_times, inherited)
values ('314759','high blood pressure','2015-07-01','4', ( if (((select count(distinct disease_name) from tbl_disease where disease_name='high blood pressure') >0), 'Y', 'N')) );
```

Removing the unneeded ones:

```
insert into tbl_disease(nid, name, diagnosed_time, treatment_times, inherited)
values ('314759','high blood pressure','2015-07-01','4', if ((select count(distinct disease_name) from tbl_disease where disease_name='high blood pressure') >0, 'Y', 'N') );
```

Comment: Thank you @ysth, when I change the subquery to  `if ( ( select count(disease_name) from tbl_disease where disease_name=@disease_name )>0 ),
    'Y','N'`, errors still

Comment: You've got an extra ) before the ,.  Get rid of it or add a matching ( after if(

Comment: thanks a lot! I think this should be the answer although the other answer is earlier.

Comment: the other answer gave you a working query, but didn't explain why you got the error you did; I thought that was worth doing