# Add MySQL column if not existing using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I know very little SQL, but found a command for SQL Server to add a column to the database if it doesn't already exist.  Sadly it doesn't work when executed against my MySQL database, returning a syntax error.

```
$query = $dbh->prepare("if not exists (select * from syscolumns where id=object_id(':table_name') and name='where') alter table :table_name add where int(2)");

if($query->execute(array(':table_name'=>'registrations'))) {
    //twist and shout
} else {
    print_r($query->errorInfo());   
}
```

So what should I change to create the column 'where int(2)' if it doesn't exist?

Comment: why do you need dynamically create a column?

Comment: You should avoid using reserved words (like WHERE) as column names.

Comment: Excellent point, I need to change that to something safer and more descriptive.  I have do this via a PHP script because it's the only way I know how with the level of access I have, I can't access the database server directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to create a stored procedure to handle this within one statement. This was discussed here: [add column to mysql table if it does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972922/add-column-to-mysql-table-if-it-does-not-exist)

Comment: Just do it and catch the resulting error. It's not how I like to work, but it's late and this needs a fix, so thank you!