# Add column if not exist

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

How could I want to add a column if not exist.
I tried this code:

```
IF EXISTS( SELECT NULL
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
           WHERE table_name = 'forwind.measuringdata_fino_10_00000000'
             AND table_schema = 'forwind'
             AND column_name != 'F1_USA(40)_u')  THEN

  ALTER TABLE `forwind.measuringdata_fino_10_00000000` ADD `F1_USA(40)_u` FLOAT NOT NULL default '0';

END IF;
```

but I get the following error:

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'IF EXISTS( SELECT NULL
>               FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

Good for me if somebody know an other solution!

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972922/add-column-to-mysql-table-if-it-does-not-exist

Comment: You also need to reverse your logic: `NOT EXISTS` and `AND column_name = 'F1_USA(40)_u'`

Comment: @ Haim Evgi the try...catch is working :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL does not support anonymous IF statements like that.

You have at least 3 options to address this:

1) Just run the `ALTER TABLE` statement and ignore the `Duplicate column name` error if the column already exists. If you're executing a bunch of DDL in a script you can use `mysql -f` to ignore the errors and keep going.
2) Use a scripting language such as bash, python, perl etc to check for the existence of the column and then add it if it does not already exist.
3) Create a stored procedure in MySQL to check for the existence of the column and then add it if it does not already exist.

P.S. As an aside, I recommend against putting parentheses in column names, because that forces you to quote the column name every time you reference it.

Answer (score 0):

```
------Add an IpAddress column in ActionsTracking table if -----

DECLARE @tableName varchar(MAX) ='ActionsTracking'
DECLARE @columnName varchar(MAX) ='IpAddress'

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns
         WHERE Name = @columnName
         AND Object_ID = Object_ID(@tableName))
   PRINT 'Column Already Exists'
ELSE
BEGIN
EXEC('ALTER TABLE '+@tableName+'
       ADD '+ @columnName +' varchar(15) null')
   PRINT 'Column Added Sucessfully'
END
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.