# alter table if fields is not already exist

Tags: mysql, sql

alter table if field is not already exist

```
ALTER TABLE `table`
 ADD( `abc` text NOT NULL,
  `xyz` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  );
```

if `abc` or `xyz` fields are already exist the can not be alter table

if it is possible ?

Comment: Why not just run the "ALTER TABLE" and check the result code?

Comment: already solved here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972922/add-column-to-mysql-table-if-it-does-not-exist

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [SHOW COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html) beforehand and construct your query accordingly, adding only fields that are missing.

Example output of `SHOW COLUMNS`:

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM City;
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Id         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Name       | char(35) | NO   |     |         |                |
| Country    | char(3)  | NO   | UNI |         |                |
| District   | char(20) | YES  | MUL |         |                |
| Population | int(11)  | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet, so I post answer: try this [link](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/mysql/howto_add_column_unless_exists.htm) for detailed example. It queries information_schema.COLUMNS table for column information about database tables.