# sql syntax error when creating column

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run the following query, but am getting a sql syntax error, but dreamweaver doesnt seem to be highlighting any error so im not sure where it is ?.
thanks :-)

```
<?php
$form_id = $_POST[form_id];
    $query = mysql_query("
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
TABLE_NAME = 'email_history' 
AND COLUMN_NAME = `$form_id`)
BEGIN
 ALTER TABLE 'email_history' ADD `$form_id` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL
END;
") or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: ‘$form_id` has different quotes..

Comment: after changing the ' to a ` I am still getting a syntax error on line 1

Comment: What is the SQL syntax error message? dreamweaver doesn't analyze SQL for you. It just sees you passing a string to a function call.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_N' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone has focused on bad quoting, but is there any chance of this query to run? Does MySQL allow such conditional statements? I know this is possible in stored routines but I have never heard of such direct usage, so I would split this into two queries: column existence check and table alteration.

This will look like this:

```
<?php
$form_id = some_function_to_check_if_input_is_valid_etc($_POST[form_id]);
$exist_result = mysql_query("SELECT IF(NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * 
    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE   TABLE_NAME  = 'email_history' 
    AND     COLUMN_NAME = '{$form_id}'
    ),1,0) AS should_alter_table
");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($exist_result);
if($row['should_alter_table']){
    mysql_query("ALTER TABLE email_history ADD `{$form_id}` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

```
‘$form_id`
```

You probably mean

```
`$form_id`
```

Update: Once more wrong quotes

```
'email_history'
```

should be

```
`email_history`
```

Remind: Backticks ` are for qualifiers (tablenames and such), where the apostroph `'` is for values.

Comment: Hi, I have changed that , but am still getting a sql syntax error on line 1

Comment: Updated. Just take a little bit more care about what is a value and what is an identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct quotation format.

```
$query = mysql_query("
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
TABLE_NAME = 'email_history' 
AND COLUMN_NAME = '$form_id')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE `email_history` ADD `$form_id` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL
END;
") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'emai' at line 1

Comment: I dont get an error with the above query, but it also doesn't create a column in email history either, even if I clear all the columns from the email_history table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$form_id = $_POST[form_id];
$query = mysql_query("
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME = 'email_history' 
    AND COLUMN_NAME = '$form_id')
  BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE `email_history` ADD `$form_id` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL
  END;
") or die(mysql_error());
```

Also, just on side note, you should never directly use the values from User input into your SQL. This is to prevent SQL injection. Here are a few links on MySQL Injection which I found:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php
http://25yearsofprogramming.com/blog/2011/20110205.htm
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_N' at line 1

Comment: I just updated my answer. Did you try this one or old one? The difference is in `AND COLUMN_NAME = '$form_id')` and ALTER TABLE `email_history`

Comment: I get this error, with the current version you have pasted >>

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_N' at line 1

Comment: A solution would be to just try alter table and handle the error if the column already exists. You would get error similar to this if the column already exists. `Duplicate column name 'newcolumnname'`. You would catch it.

Comment: how can I dismiss the error, as this solution would be ok if I could get rid of the error.

Comment: I tried this, but when you edit the form it then creates a new column for the form

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6296/discussion-between-virendra-and-iain-simpson)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$form_id = $_POST[form_id];
    $query = mysql_query("
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
TABLE_NAME = 'email_history' 
AND COLUMN_NAME = '$form_id')
BEGIN
 ALTER TABLE email_history ADD `$form_id` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL
END;
") or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'e' at line 1

Comment: Just found this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972922/add-column-to-mysql-table-if-it-does-not-exist