# MySQL add column if not exist

Tags: mysql, sql

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'email_subscription' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'subscribe_all')
  THEN 
  ALTER TABLE email_subscription
  ADD COLUMN subscribe_all TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1,
  ADD COLUMN subscribe_category varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL;
```

I had a look at huge amount of examples. but this query doesn't work, I got error of:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM
>   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS   WHERE TABLE_NAME =' at line 1

Comment: Are you doing this inside a stored procedure? The `IF ELSE` isn't valid outside a procedure or function.

Comment: Hey, I see ! I do have a proceedure  covered on top and didn;t work as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add column to mysql table if it does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972922/add-column-to-mysql-table-if-it-does-not-exist)

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972922/add-column-to-mysql-table-if-it-does-not-exist

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can create a procedure for the query,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Alter_Table()
BEGIN
    DECLARE _count INT;
    SET _count = (  SELECT COUNT(*) 
                    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                    WHERE   TABLE_NAME = 'email_subscription' AND 
                            COLUMN_NAME = 'subscribe_all');
    IF _count = 0 THEN
        ALTER TABLE email_subscription
            ADD COLUMN subscribe_all TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1,
            ADD COLUMN subscribe_category varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL;
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: There is logical error in script, if table not exists the `Count` = 0 also. You need first check for table existence, then for column.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan i'm assuming that the table provided existed.

Comment: I got You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@count INT;

Comment: Hey bralliant, it now passes. do I have to call this function somewhere to make it running?

Comment: Actually, it's working, I just run call Alter_Table() and it works ! thanks !

Answer (score 32):

If your host doesn't give you permission to create or run procedures, I think I found another way to do this using PREPARE/EXECUTE and querying the schema:

```
SET @s = (SELECT IF(
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE table_name = 'table_name'
        AND table_schema = DATABASE()
        AND column_name = 'col_name'
    ) > 0,
    "SELECT 1",
    "ALTER TABLE table_name ADD col_name VARCHAR(100)"
));

PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Excellent for use in _ad hoc_ scripts.

Answer (score 3):

You are using MS SQL Server syntax in MySQL.

Comment: Hah! I knew something was off but I couldn't put my finger on it :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no equivalent syntax to achieve this in a single MySQL statement.

To get something simlilar, you can either

1) attempt to add the column with an ALTER TABLE, and let MySQL raise an error if a column of that name already exists in the table, or

2) query the information_schema.columns view to check if a column of that name exists in the table.

Note that you really do need to check for the table_schema, as well as the table_name:

```
SELECT column_name
  FROM information_schema.columns 
 WHERE table_schema = 'foo'
   AND table_name   = 'email_subscription'
   AND column_name  = 'subscribe_all'
```

and based on that, decide whether to run the ALTER TABLE

Answer (score 2):

Also add condition for database name to check column existance.

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_AlterTable()
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbName' AND 
                         TABLE_NAME = 'email_subscription' AND 
                         COLUMN_NAME = 'subscribe_all') THEN 
       ALTER TABLE email_subscription
          ADD COLUMN subscribe_all TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1,
          ADD COLUMN subscribe_category VARCHAR(512) DEFAULT NULL;
    END IF; 
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @s = (SELECT IF(
    (SELECT COUNT(column_name)
          FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
          WHERE table_name = 'oc_bitcoin_wallets_receive'
          AND table_schema = 'k_opencart2'
          AND column_name = 'test3'
    ) > 0,
    "SELECT 1",
    "ALTER TABLE `oc_bitcoin_wallets_receive` ADD COLUMN `test3` INT NOT NULL AFTER `test2`;"
));
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Values for edit:
    oc_bitcoin_wallets_receive - table name,
    k_opencart2 - database name,
    test3 - name of new column,
    oc_bitcoin_wallets_receive - second location table
    test3 - second location column,
    test2 - name of column before new column.