# MySQL Procedure: If column don't exists create it

Tags: mysql, procedure, information-schema

I try to make procedure that create non-exists column in my MySQL table like here:
[MySQL add column if not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381895/mysql-add-column-if-not-exist)

**My procedure:**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Alter_Table(IN _table_name TEXT,IN _column_name TEXT,IN _column_type TEXT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE _count INT;
    SET _count = (  SELECT COUNT(*) 
                    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                    WHERE   TABLE_NAME = _table_name AND 
                            COLUMN_NAME = _column_name);
    IF _count = 0 THEN
        ALTER TABLE _table_name ADD COLUMN _column_name _column_type;
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

**But I have an error:**

```
#1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax obok '_column_type; END IF; END' w linii 9
```

Anyone know **why**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... I make it in PHP...

```
function alter_table($table_name, $column_name, $column_type) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                 WHERE TABLE_NAME = `$table_name` AND COLUMN_NAME = `$column_name`");
    if(!$result) {
        mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `$table_name`
            ADD COLUMN `$column_name` $column_type");
    }
}
```

Comment: Names cannot be properly parametrised, so you would either need to build the query dynamically or use PHP's macro substitution kind of parametrisation, as you did here. Please consider accepting your own answer formally to thus mark the question as solved.