# Update MySQL database table schema

Tags: mysql, database

I want to update a MySQL database schema (with MySQL code) but I am unfortunately not sure of the state of the tables, as they are distributed..

Let's say some 'clients' have a table called "user" with a schema like

```
name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
password VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
```

I want to add an `email` column, but it's possible that they already have an email column (depending on their installation version).

How can I run a command that ensures that there is a `email` column and does nothing if it's already there? Keep in mind I would be doing this for many tables that are more complex.

I know I could be creating temp tables and re-populating (and will if it's the only solution) but I figure there might be some kind of `CREATE` or `UPDATE` table command that has "oh you already have that column, skip" logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Alter_MyTable()
BEGIN
    DECLARE _count INT;
    SET _count = (  SELECT COUNT(*) 
                    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                    WHERE   TABLE_NAME = 'user' AND 
                            COLUMN_NAME = 'email');
    IF _count = 0 THEN
        ALTER TABLE user
            ADD COLUMN email varchar(512);
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

or rather make it a generic stored procedure like this:

```
create procedure AddColumnIfDoesntExists(
    IN dbName tinytext,
    IN tableName tinytext,
    IN fieldName tinytext,
    IN fieldDef text)
begin
    IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
        WHERE column_name=fieldName
        and table_name=tableName
        and table_schema=dbName
        )
    THEN
        set @ddl=CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',dbName,'.',tableName,
            ' ADD COLUMN ',fieldName,' ',fieldDef);
        prepare stmt from @ddl;
        execute stmt;
    END IF;
end;
//

delimiter ';'
```

Comment: Would there be a pragmatic way to do this for every column for every table, or would I need to do it individually?

Comment: @tdoakiiii:- Updated my answer with a generic stored procedure. Now you need to call this stored procedure by providing the tablename and columname. Hope that helps :)

Comment: @tdoakiiii:- Call it like `call AddColumnIfDoesntExists(Database(), 'user', 'email', 'varchar(100) null');`

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. This will not gen an error if the column already exists right?

Comment: I'm getting an error on the line  ' ADD COLUMN ',fieldName,' ',fieldDef);  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 15

Answer (score 1):

If the column already exists the `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN` statement will throw an error, so if you are thinking that you might lose data because of trying to add a column that already exists that won't be the case, if any you need to handle error. See [add column to mysql table if it does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972922/add-column-to-mysql-table-if-it-does-not-exist)

There are also resources telling you how to deal with these with store procedures, etc. See [MySQL add column if not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381895/mysql-add-column-if-not-exist).

Hope it helps.

Comment: The issue is I don't know if one column is missing or 5 or missing, and I was trying to avoid a mess of add columns. Instead I was wishing for a magic "update" procedure without going through each column. This is the result of no foresight prior to me jumping in.