# create table if not exists, insert columns if missing, best way

Tags: mysql, multiple-columns, create-table

I need to create a table if it doesnt exist, and add missing columns in the proper order if the table already exists.

I know how to do it with lots of queries, and if statements and so on, but what I am asking here is what the best solution would be.. Maybe there is a special query to do this, or a smart way.

I would do it this way:

- create table if not exists (all columns as they should be)
- compare all the columns (if some are missing they will be added, else not)

Is this the best way or are there better ways to do it?

---

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

the colums need to be added at the right position. I have a list of strings representing all the columns in the proper order. using vb.net I am iterating through these strings.

Comment: Do you have data that you need to keep? If not, drop everything and then add it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972922/add-column-to-mysql-table-if-it-does-not-exist) for instance. It's basically about querying the data dictionary and adding columns only if they do not exist:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
               WHERE table_name = 'tablename'
                 AND table_schema = 'db_name'
                 AND column_name = 'columnname') THEN

  ALTER TABLE `TableName` ADD `ColumnName` int(1) NOT NULL default '0';

END IF;
```

Putting it in a procedure makes it quite handy.

**p.s.** note about column positions: from [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

> To add a column at a specific position within a table row, use FIRST
>   or AFTER col_name. The default is to add the column last. You can also
>   use FIRST and AFTER in CHANGE or MODIFY operations to reorder columns
>   within a table.

Comment: thanks! does this also add the column in the right position? i mean, i have a list of strings representing the columns in vb.net and would need them to be added in the same order. so it could be that a column in the middle of the table is missing..

Comment: Let me put it this way: it can! ;) If you call your `AddCol(...)` procedure in the order of the columns - then "yes". However, if you need to insert a column in between, you've to add the position using `AFTER`. Check the docs for details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use following codes for that:

```
if not exists(select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'table_name' and COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name')

BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE table_name ADD
    ToUser uniqueidentifier NULL

END
```