# SQL: ALTER new column IF NOT EXISTS - how?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I'm trying to `ALTER` a new column `IF NOT EXITS`. I modified the code of the third answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972922/add-column-to-mysql-table-if-it-does-not-exist):

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myUpgrade $$
CREATE PROCEDURE myUpgrade()
BEGIN

IF NOT EXISTS
    ((SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = DATABASE() AND`COLUMN_NAME` = 'myNewColumn' `TABLE_NAME` = 'my_table'))
THEN
    ALTER TABLE `my_table` ADD `myNewColumn` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL AFTER `id`;
ENDIF;

END $$

CALL myUpgrade() $$

DELIMITER;
```

**Error**:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your  MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`TABLE_NAME` = 'my_table'))
THEN
    ALTER TABLE `my_table` ADD `myNewColumn` VA' at line 5
```

Maybe useful:

- I run the code in PHPMyAdmin (4.0.10deb1)
- Server version: 5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
- Protocol-Version: 10
- Apache/2.4.7
- Database-Client version: libmysql - 5.5.38
- PHP-Extension: mysqli

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are missing an `AND` operator between `'myNewColumn' TABLE_NAME`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an `AND` before the `TABLE_NAME` condition in the `WHERE` clause:

```
IF NOT EXISTS
    ((SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
      WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = DATABASE() 
        AND `COLUMN_NAME` = 'myNewColumn'
        AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'my_table'))
```

Also, there needs to be a space in `END IF`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missinhg AND 
'myNewColumn' and `TABLE_NAME`

That particular part should look like this:

((SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = DATABASE() AND`COLUMN_NAME` = 'myNewColumn' **AND** `TABLE_NAME` = 'my_table'))